# OpenCV windows in Qt gui application

Tags: qt, opencv

I have Qt gui application working with OpenCV.

Sometimes it's nice to use OpenCV imshow() to show images during program work (for debug).
I just simply use:

```
cv::imshow("roi",roiImg);
```

in Qt application.

In Windows 7 everything works fine. Only when debugging in QtCreator I'm getting segfault when trying to show OpenCV window.

But my problem is that in WindowsXP even when running application exe both compiled as debug and release version program crashes.

Has anyone similiar problem? What is the best solution? What solution do you use as debug image output in applications written in Qt for example?

Comment: Have you tried nameWindow and then imshow ? Are you sure it is imshow related ?

Comment: Yes I've tried namedWindow and waitKey after imshow(). I've tried also without wait key. Program fails where imshow is I've checked it by printing some debug before and after. On Win7 works ok so I think that it is imshow related. I've showed Qt window with image there and problem disapeared, but as I said creating Qt windows etc. is little inconvinient for debug reasons. I've also tried to catch some cv exceptions but it throws any.

Comment: imshow should never core dump but it does more often than not see https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python/issues/501